# Github Authentication

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit, github-for-mac

I apologize if this is a newbie question. I have been working on trying to get a few projects on GitHub for hours.

I am logged in to the application:

[image]

But whenever I try to push or pull I get:

[image]

I was initially trying to connect on Eclipse but was running into authentication errors as well. What  am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure:

- your remote repo references the remote repo read-write address https://github.com/DavidTunnell/delivery-driver-wage-calculator.git,
- check if GitHub did register an ssh key in your GitHub admin ssh section.
  That key should be named `GitHub for Mac - yourHostname`.
- don't forget to add your GitHub username and email in the "GitHub for Mac" options section.

Comment: When you say "don't forget to add your GitHub username and email in the "GitHub for Mac" options section." do you mean there is somewhere on the website I should add this? As is shown on the pic above im logged into the GitHub for Mac application.

Comment: here is my current error message after I changed from ssh to https per your suggestion: "To https://github.com/DavidTunnell/delivery-driver-wage-calculator.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/DavidTunnell/delivery-driver-wage-calculator.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
 (256)"

Comment: @DavidTunnell looks better. What if you pull now, before you push again?

Comment: Victory is ours. Thank you so much!